# vue.js updating input box with input from another input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a converter, where I type a number in one box, and it converts and outputs its conversion into another box.  For this example, I am using temperatures.  The code does what I would expect it to, however, it only does it after the input box loses focus.

For example, if I have a 20 in the first box, I would have a conversion of 20 in the second box.  If I delete the 0 in the first box, I would expect it to instantly update in the second box.  However as it stands, only after I click into the second box does it update.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form id='calculate'>
    <label>Centigrade
      <input id='c' v-model.number='cent' type='number' @change='validate()'>
    </label>
    <label>Fahrenheit
      <input id='f' v-model.number='fahren' type='number' @change='validate()'>
    </label>
  </form>
<!--     {{calculateCentigrade}}
    {{calcuateFahrenheit}} -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //(F − 32) × 5/9
      //(C × 9/5) + 32
      cent: 20,
      fahren: 68,   
    };
  },
  computed: {
    calculateCentigrade(){
      return ((this.fahren-32)*(5/9)).toFixed(2)
    },
    calcuateFahrenheit(){
      return ((this.cent*(9/5))+32).toFixed(2)
  
}
  },
  methods: {
    validate(){
      if(event.target.id === 'f'){
        this.cent = ((this.fahren-32)*5/9).toFixed(2)
      }
      else{
        this.fahren = ((this.cent*9/5)+32).toFixed(2)
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

working example: https://codepen.io/PaulRC/pen/WNoqbXY

I thought that it might be that I needed to use computed and if you uncomment this section `<!--     {{calculateCentigrade}} {{calcuateFahrenheit}} -->` you would see that the compute model runs when the inputs are changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a watcher property and the binding using `v-model` :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <form id='calculate'>
    <label>Centigrade
      <input  v-model.number='cent' type='number'>
    </label>
    <label>Fahrenheit
      <input  v-model.number='fahren' type='number' >
    </label>
   </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cent: 20,
      fahren: 68,   
    };
  },
  watch:{
    cent(newVal){
      this.fahren=((newVal*(9/5))+32).toFixed(2)
    },
      fahren(newVal){
      this.cent=((newVal-32)*5/9).toFixed(2)
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is the way that I was just thinking actually.  However, it does not like multiple digits.  For example, if I try to type '78' it will only take the '7' because then it will start the converting.

Comment: @PaulCarlson In your question you seem to be complaining that your current code is NOT instantly converting when you remove a digit (due to using change event instead of input event), but now with this solution you are complaining that the code IS instantly converting when you enter a new digit.  Possibly rethink your design or what your ultimate goal is.  You may want to add a 'convert' button and handler so that the conversion doesn't happen until the user is ready.